# Парсинг комментариев Instagram

Tags: парсер, instagram

Реализую проект для магистерской диссертации. В рамках проекта необходима выгрузка комментариев из Instagram для их дальнейшего семантического анализа, выявления ключевых слов и кластеризации. Не могу разобраться как решить первую часть задания. Изучив то, что предлагает Google столкнулся с проблемами:

1) API Instagram на данный момент закрыто для общего пользования и выдается только по требованию. Тут сразу первый вопрос. Как считаете имеет ли смысл его запрашивать, учитывая, что проект чисто научный и не коммерческий?

2) Все существующие сервисы нацелены на выгрузку комментариев к конкретному посту (делают это по ссылке на определенный пост). А как поступить если нужны комментарии ко всем постам в целевом паблике?

Прошу советов для понимания в каком направлении двигаться. Еще раз сформулирую цель. Задача:

Выгрузить все комментарии ко всем постам в целевом паблике (скажем в CSV файл) для их дальнейшего анализа силами Python.

Заранее благодарю за помощь!